# Application on phone displays different stuff than in Unity and Nox with same code

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine

The problem looks like this :

```
Text finalCost;
float one = 1
float two = 12.99
```

So now I have to multiply them and display them in the text field using .ToString() method;

```
finalCost.text = (one * two).ToString();
```

Okay, when I test it in Unity, it displays correctly 12,99 (the dot is turned into a comma) : 
[image] 
Then I build the application with .apk extension and install it on Nox with Android 7.
This is what Nox shows me :

[image]

Same happens on an actual phone with Android 10 :

[image]

**The actual number doesn't matter, it's the fact that the number is being displayed without the comma which matters to me a lot and I was wondering why does this happen?**

Comment: Welcome to localisation.   Where 27.78 can be the same as 27,68 or the format 2,768 is also valid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, it turns out to be about your current locale and the way your country handles the "," thing in float, different countries do it differently and that's why sometimes it broke.

All I had to do is to use this when trying to parse a float :

```
floatNumber1 += float.Parse(floatNumber2, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.Any, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

To ensure to use the dot symbol.